# argparse: how to parse a single string argument OR a file listing many arguments?

Tags: python, argparse

I have a use case where I'd like the user to be able to provide, as an argument to argparse, EITHER a single string OR a filename where each line has a string.

Assume the user launches `./myscript.py -i foobar`

The logical flow I'm looking for is something like this:

The script determines whether the string foobar is a readable file.
IF it is indeed a readable file, we call some function from the script, passing each line in `foobar` as an argument to that function.  If foobar is not a readable file, we call the same function but just use the string `foobar` as the argument and return.

I have no ability to guarantee that a filename argument will have a specific extension (or even an extension at all).

Is there a more pythonic way to do this OTHER than just coding up the logic exactly as I've described above?   I looked through the [argparse tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html) and didn't see anything, but it also seems reasonable to think that there would be some specific hooks for filenames as arguments, so I figured I'd ask.

Comment: Take a look at [os.path.exists](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists)

Answer (score 1):

A way would be:

Let's say that you have created a parser like this:

```
parser.add_argument('-i',  
                    help='...', 
                    type=function)
```

Where `type` points to the `function` which will be an outer function that evaluates the input of the user and decides if it is a `string` or a `filename`

More information about `type` you can find in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type).

Here is a minimal example that demonstrates this use of `type`:

```
parser.add_argument('-d','--directory', 
                    type=Val_dir, 
                    help='...')
# ....

def Val_dir(dir):
    if not os.path.isdir(dir):
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError('The directory you specified does not seem to exist!')
    else:
        return dir
```

The above example shows that with `type` we can control the input at parsing time. Of course in your case the function would implement another logic - evaluate if the input is a string or a filename.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like an `argparse` problem, since all you want from it is a string.  That string can be a filename or a function argument.  To a `parser` these will look the same.  Also `argparse` isn't normally used to run functions.  It is used to parse the commandline.  Your code determines what to do with that information.

So here's a script (untested) that I think does your task:

```
import argparse
def somefunction(*args):
    print(args)

if __name__=='__main__':
    parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-i','--input')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    try:
        with open(args.input) as f:
            lines = f.read()
            somefunction(*lines)
            # or
            # for line in lines:
            #   somefuncion(line.strip())
    except:
        somefunction(arg.input)
```

`argparse` just provides the `args.input` string.  It's the try/except block that determines how it is used.

================

Here's a prefix char approach:

```
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars='@',
   description="use <prog -i @filename> to load values from file")
parser.add_argument('-i','--inputs')
args=parser.parse_args()
for arg in args.inputs:
     somefunction(arg)
```

this is supposed to work with a file like:

```
 one
 two 
 three
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#fromfile-prefix-chars